# Animated marker-like text-highlighting on scroll

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, css-animations

I'm tying to recreate the effect that can be seen on this page:

http://people.com/chica/gabriel-zamora-male-beauty-influencer/

If you wait for it to completely load, then scroll past the "His passion for makeup began with one simple desire" part, you'll notice text being highlighed with a yellow background as it is scrolled into view.

Trying to figure out the most elegant and lightweight way to achieve this (I'm thinking CSS3+Jquery)?

Comment: Since we don't write up code here, you'll need to provide us with a working code snippet with what you have so far. And when external links die, this question will be useless for future users, so also provide the expected result within the question, either by word or image(s) ... and you should know all this by now

Comment: there's one plugin available for this kind of purpose. It's scroll-magic, a jQuery plugin which will allow you to animate DOM elements based on scroll position.

Answer (score 1):

Its not completely clear what exactly you want help with here. But by inspecting the code on the site you´re refering to it seems they are using a gradient as a background and then animating that background position. This can be achieved through either CSS animation or changing the elements background position with javascript or jQuery. Here is my example:

HTML:

```
<p>
Some text before
<span id="hightlight">Your text here</span>
Some text after
</p>
```

CSS With CSS-animation:

```
#hightlight{    
    background-size: 200% auto; 
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right,#fff 50%,#ff0 50%);
    background-position: 0% 0;

    animation-name: highlight;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes highlight {
    from {background-position: 0% 0;}
    to {background-position: -100% 0;}
}
```

This will give you an animation using the CSS Keyframes. Alternatively you can use javascript and CSS like this:

CSS:

```
#hightlight{
    transition: 1s; 
    background-size: 200% auto; 
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right,#fff 50%,#ff0 50%);
    background-position: 0% 0;
}
```

And javascript:

```
document.getElementById("hightlight").style.backgroundPosition = "-100% 0";
```